# Is purchaseToken unique in Android in-app purchase?

Tags: android, node.js, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I have a project in which i have to verify the in-app purchase in my back-end(Node js).
**The purchase is one-time consumable purchase.**
i.e user is paying some dollars to buy a package named Diamond that gives him 1000 coins.

so my question is if user has purchased a package Diamond if he buy the same package again will I get unique purchaseToken in request?